# How resilient is the .7z file format?

Tags: backup, compression, 7-zip

I'm intended to package up quite a lot of data in to archives so that I can store them using an on-line file storage service and to various local backups - the intention being that this will be fairly long term static storage.

I'm currently planning to compress them using 7zip into **.7z** files, but I'd rather compress the folder tree in large chucks, such that each archive will contain ~350Mb-1Gb of data (*before* compression) and I'm wondering how resilient the format is to damage.

Is the archive structured such that "minor" damage can be corrected?
Or if the damage is "serious", will it destroy the *entire* archive - or just those files in the specific site of the damage within the archive?

Essentially, the hidden question here is: should I package in to lots of small separate archives or few large ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any compression tool is going to be subject to corruption issues on very large files.  Your best bet is probably to use smaller files, but *NOT* volumes of a larger archive - as separate archives.

AFAIK 7zip will lose the whole archive if you have file damage in a portion of the archive.

Comment: This.  While some schemes are better than others, any compression scheme risks killing the whole archive depending on the damage, and the larger the file the more likely this is.

Comment: That's what I thought. Oh well, lots of small archives and copious checksums it is. Thanks.

Comment: How large is very large?

Answer (score 6):

7-zip will lose the whole archive even if there are only minor corruptions. This is because 7-zip only use [solid compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression), which means that all files are agglomerated together. However, 7-zip authors offer a tutorial on how to [manually try to fix your 7zip archive here](http://www.7-zip.org/recover.html).

If you want to be able to recover non corrupted files from a corrupted archive, you have to make a non-solid archive, such as a zip with DEFLATE. I tried several formats, including ARC which allows non-solid archives, but it was less resilient than zip. There is also the PEA format (by PEAzip) which allows for partial extraction, and RAR (by WinRAR) which specifically has an option ["keep broken files"](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/28/repair-extract-broken-rar-archives/) to allow partial extraction.

You can try by yourself various compression formats and see if you can still uncompress your data using [a simple data tampering python tool](https://github.com/lrq3000/pyFileFixity/blob/master/pyFileFixity/filetamper.py).

Comment: It sounds like ZIP should be the preferred format. I want to compress + encrypt some documents. And was wondering which format to use...

Comment: @akostadinov Yes, ZIP with DEFLATE algo is more future proof because it is a non-solid archive so it allows partial extraction. That said, compression is always much less future-proof than raw files. Encryption is another layer that can cause files to be unrecoverable.

Comment: If it encrypts per file, not per whole archive, that would probably make it. Maybe I can try flipping some bits in the archive to see if only one file or more would be broken to extract.. I don't really anticipate such corruption but I prefer to err on the safe side.

Comment: @akostadinov I'm sure you can find algorithms or even just tools that work by compressing per file, but then you will have poor compression since the goal of compression is to find recurring patterns that can be summarized in less symbols. So such a per file compression strategy would only be worthwhile when compressing huge files, then you have enough data to find repetitive symbols, but even then compression ratio will always be worse than when compressing multiple files.

Comment: For my purpose max compression is not necessary. Even compression not fully needed but would be nice to keep the file size in check. More I need the encryption part.

Comment: @akostadinov For encryption it's the same principle, you want an encryption scheme that allows to decrypt other untampered blocks even if one block is corrupted. This type of encryption scheme is called block-based encryption, and is implemented for example in [DAR](http://dar.linux.free.fr/). I wrote more details about these encryption schemes [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyFileFixity/#table-of-contents).

Answer (score 5):

If you want redundancy in your compression, I would suggest using rar/par/par2 files.  This has been a standard for compression redundancy for files sent over newsgroups and a lot of other sources.  You split your files into many rar files... and you can even be missing entire rar files and still recover your data.  For data that doesn't compress well, this could actually increase the total size, but that is the price you pay for redundancy.

Comment: +1 for RAR/PAR.  There's no better way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs it might be better to introduce the redundancy on another level. What I want to say is you rather think about another complete copy of the files rather than trying to alleviate partial damage. Then you regularly check the checksums of these files and whenever a problem arises you replace the defective hardware and copy from an intact backup again.